# Trying to Run Slope Analysis Script

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, slope

I'm trying to make a slope raster from a lot of DEM`s.

The DEM rasters are in this file Geodatabase 
`C:\Bachelorarbeit\Daten\GIs\Originale\dtk25_dgm1.gdb`
The slope raster should be saved in this file Geodatabase 
`C:\Users\Hans im Glück\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb`

Is it possible to use spaces in my pathname?

I have ArcGIS 10.3 and found this basic script on ESRI's website:

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:/sapyexamples/data"
outSlope = Slope("elevation", "DEGREE", 1)
outSlope.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/outslope01")
```

How to I execute this script on multiple  DEM's contained within a folder?

Comment: Yes, you can have spaces in your pathnames. To get a list of rasters in your GDB, you'll want to use [ListRasters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listrasters.htm) with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

As your DEM data is in a file geodatabase then you will note 3 things about the file names:

- They do not start with a number
- They do not have spaces in their names
- They are unique names

As @Paul says in the comment you can create a list and loop through this. You could just use the name of the DEM for the output name of your slope raster, that would be simplest but it may be prudent to change it in some way to indicate it is a slope raster. You could easily do that at the point when you save your raster.